# Service fails to start if StandardOutput path is removed

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a service configured to log `StandardOutput` to a log location. Some users may delete the log path when gathering logs data. If I restart my service and the path does not exist, my service fails. Is there a way to work around it? The solutions in order of preference is

```
[Unit]
Description=Some service

[Service]
ExecStart=<some_path>/start_service.sh
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=append:<path_to_logs>/service-stdout.log

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

1. Create the path where StandardOutput will be logged. Tried this with StartExecPre and with my service script itself but didn't work.

`ExecStartPre=mkdir -p <path_to_logs>`

2. Ignore that the path does not exist and just continue without logging anything at all.
3. Log to a default location. Tried to find the output in the journal but I don't see it at all. Is it really logged by default if not StandardOutput parameter is specified in the service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, in my case the systemd service keeps working if the file is removed. What systemd version are you using?

Comment: Why the redirection? Why not just let systemd handle it all? If you really want it, then direct it to an area where users only have read and not delete rights. I'd also be having a nark at any user who is deleting them when they should not.

Answer (score 1):

[`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) says:

> append:path is similar to file:path above, but it opens the file in append mode.
>
> The file:path option ... If path refers to a regular file on the filesystem, it is opened (created if it doesn't exist yet) ...

So the file shouldn't need to exist.  The directory it exists in, however probably does need to exist.

There are a few ways to ensure your logging directory exists:

1. If your software is packaged, add a `mkdir -p /var/log/...` to the `postinst`.  This will create a persistent directory.  This is trivial so I won't go into more detail.
2. [tmpfiles.d](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html).  This will ensure the directory exists.  If it is deleted (or exists on a tmpfs), it will be re-created on the next boot.   This is how systemd ensures `/run/log/journal` and `/var/log/journal` exist.
3. `LogsDirectory=` can be used to create a log directory when starting the unit.
4. Path units.  You can create an entirely new unit called "myservice.path" which ensures the directory is created when started and will watch that directory.  When that directory is deleted, this unit can trigger a service to run `mkdir -p` to re-create it.

---

#### Tmpfiles.d:

If you want:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/myservice/log.log
```

Then create this file:

```
# /etc/tmpfiles.d/myservice.conf
#Type Path               Mode User Group Age  Argument
d     /var/log/myservice 0755 root root  -    -
```

In this case, your users can read this directory, but they can't delete it (without admin permissions).  If it is deleted, it can be re-created via restarting `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` or rebooting.

#### LogsDirectory=

`man tmpfiles.d` says:

> System daemons frequently require private runtime directories... For these, it is better to use RuntimeDirectory= in their unit files (see systemd.exec(5) for details), if the flexibility provided by tmpfiles.d is not required. The advantages are that the configuration required by the unit is centralized in one place, and that the lifetime of the directory is tied to the lifetime of the service itself. Similarly, ..., LogsDirectory=, ... should be used to create directories under ... /var/log/ ...  tmpfiles.d should be used for files whose lifetime is independent of any service or requires more complicated configuration.

Therefore, it may be better to use [`LogsDirectory=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=).

One advantage is that if your users delete the directory, it'll be automatically created whenever the service is restarted.

Here's an example:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=<some_path>/start_service.sh
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/myservice/service-stdout.log
LogsDirectory=myservice
```

The path of the directory is also available to your service as environment variable `$LOGS_DIRECTORY`.

The disadvantage of this solution is that you assume your directory will always be created in `/var/log`.  This might not be true in some sandboxed configurations (possibly when using `DynamicUser=`) or if you move this unit to the `--user` bus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for logs in journal, you need to set stdout to syslog `StandaedOutput=syslog` and restart the `rsyslog` service with `systemctl restart rsyslog`

Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file

Comment: FYI, in the latest releases of systemd, `StandardOutput=syslog` is no longer documented.  IIRC, Debian 9 man pages said something like "On most systems, this behaves the same as `journal`")  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=